# Can you pass specific text within a line to an external command?

Tags: external-command, range

#### Background

Vim uses [ranges](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Ranges) to specify which **lines** should be passed to a command. For example, `:5,10` will use **lines** 5-10, `:'a,'b` will use the **lines** between mark `a` and mark `b`, and `:'<,'>` will use the **lines** that are selected in visual mode.

#### Question

Is there a way to do this with sub-line granularity? What if I want to use only part of a line instead of the whole line?

#### Example use case

I want to pass some text within my file into an external shell program. For example, I can use `write_c` (see `:help w_c`) to pass some text into `cat`, which will just print it out. Let's say I have the following file:

```
hello
this is my file
goodbye
```

and I put my cursor on the `m`. Then I use <kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode and <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to go to the next `e`. Now my visual selection is `my file`. If I then press <kbd>:</kbd> to enter command mode and type `:w !cat` (so the entire command is `:'<,'>:w !cat`), then I see the message `this is my file`, when I only wanted to see `my file` because the entire line that the visual selection was on got piped into `cat`.

How can I select just `my file` and pipe only that part into `cat`?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://superuser.com/a/1763212/537967) to cross-reference the original source of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @romainl for the help. Here's a solution that uses yanking and seems to work well:

1. <kbd>y</kbd> to yank the selection
2. `:!echo`  to start the command
3. `<C-r>=escape(substitute(shellescape(getreg('"')), '\n', '\r', 'g'), '#%!')<CR>`  to put the contents of the `"` register into the command line
4. `<Bar> cat` to pipe the result into `cat` (for example)
5. `<CR><CR>` to run the command

An example overall mapping looks like this:

```
vnoremap <C-c> y:!echo <C-r>=escape(substitute(shellescape(getreg('"')), '\n', '\r', 'g'), '#%!')<CR> <Bar> clip.exe<CR><CR>
```

Using this, I can map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> in visual mode to copy text to the clipboard using `clip.exe` in WSL.

So far this works for all the visual highlight cases I have tested:

- normal text
- multiline text
- text including `'`, `"`, `(`, `)`, `#`, `%`, or `!`
- visual block selections
- text ending in a newline (including visual line mode selections)

So I'm happy with it for now. Hopefully there isn't some weird case I come across later that breaks it...

Comment: I did come across a weird case that broke it. `%` expands to the filename of the current buffer, so I couldn't copy that character. I updated the answer and added `%` to the list of escaped characters passed into the `escape` function to solve this issue.

Comment: I also needed to add `#` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

You can't. Ex commands are always linewise and there is no way around that.

### Long answer

You *can* achieve your goal, though, just not with `:help :range!` or any other Ex command.

You can start with a relatively straightforward method (that happens to fit your simple example):

```
vfe
y
:w !cat <C-r>"<CR>
```

but it quickly becomes rather complex when you start to deal with multiline text, special characters, etc.. And then, you have to consider what the external command expects: does it need `\n`-terminated line? does it handle multiline? what about quoting and expansion? etc.

Here is the same example, but with *some* sanitization added:

```
:w !cat <C-r>=shellescape(getreg('"'))<CR>
```

This is starting to become a lot more involved than:

```
:'<,'>w !cat
```

and we are not doing anything even remotely useful with that text.

See `:help system()` for another even more involved approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had tried the possibility of yanking and pasting, but I didn't understand `shellescape` until now. I was able to combine stuff to get a working solution, which I posted as a separate answer.